# Ruby / sinatra - How to ouput JSON

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to format my output as json. Here is a test code from http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/json.html :

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/json"

# define a route that uses the helper
get '/' do
  json :foo => 'bar'
end

# The rest of your classic application code goes here...
```

It shows me an "Application Error". Maybe it comes from the other files to launch the app. I'm using heroku(cloud). So I have a Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0'
gem 'thin'
```

Gemfile.lock :

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    daemons (1.1.9)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    rack (1.5.2)
    sinatra (1.1.0)
      rack (~> 1.1)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    tilt (1.4.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  sinatra (= 1.1.0)
  thin
```

and Procfile :

```
web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -p $PORT
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: I have an "Application Error"

Comment: What type of application error? If you're deploying to Heroku, you should install a logging platform like papertrail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference in your Gemfile `json` gem, e.g:

```
gem "json", "1.5.5"
```

And then you call `.to_json` on the object you want to output as JSON.

Comment: How do I get my json version of sinatra ? I'm no using .to_json, is it a ruby syntaxe ? I need to have an output like : HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: when you install this json gem "to_json" will be available